# How to use python to make a discord bot output an image

Tags: python, image, discord, bots

I am new to making discord bots, and new to python. I've tried looking up answers elsewhere, but I could not find any. I am trying to make a bot for a game i am playing, for ex: if the user does $armour it will display a small picture of the armour and the stats of it. I've imported both the discord and PIL modules. All my code seems to work except the part where I try to make the bot display my image. When I do $armour it responds with <bound method Image.show of <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=P size=32x32 at 0x7F698A777070>> and not an image. I have not got very far into it yet so its not that organized, but i believe the code should work. Any help or advice on discord bot making will be appreciated.
'''

```
import discord
import os
import image
import PIL
client = discord.Client()
from PIL import Image
armour = Image.open("Void_Coil.png")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('hello there')
    if message.content.startswith('$armour'):
        await message.channel.send(armour.show)
```

Comment: Have you tried to provide the full path?

Comment: @Dominik       Ive tried doing 'Image.open(r"C:\Users\digit\OneDrive\Desktop\Void_Coil.png")'                                                 but that didn't work at all, said it didn't exist even tho i copied the file path, also im using an IDE, i uploaded the file to it and it show up on the directory in the IDE, so i should just be able to open it like how i coded it originialy